# Error in (function (optimizer = "bobyqa", restart_edge = TRUE, boundary.tol = 1e-05)

Tags: r, optimization, lme4

I´m trying to run a `glmm` with `gaussian()` family for counting data as response variable, a log transformed variable as fixed factor and a nested random effect:

```
firsttry<-glmer(spm~logterrisize + (1|studyarea/teriid),
     data = Data_table_for_analysis_Character_studyarea,
     family = gaussian(), 
            control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",
                            optCtrl=list(maxfun=3e11)))
```

Then I'm getting this error message:

> Error in (function (optimizer = "bobyqa", restart_edge = TRUE, boundary.tol = 1e-05,  : unused arguments (tolPwrss = 1e-07, compDev = TRUE, nAGQ0initStep = TRUE, checkControl = list("ignore", "stop", "ignore", "stop", "stop", "message+drop.cols", "warning", "stop", "stop"), checkConv = list(list("warning", 0.001, NULL), list("ignore", 1e-04), list("warning", 1e-06)))

Unfortunately and even after a long search on the internet I still do not know what I am exactly supposed to do with that message. I tried to use that optimization tools or exclude some, but the error message is still the same.

For more info, these are the data:

[image]

---

```
show(spm)[1] 18.461538 22.641509 35.172414 10.418006 15.611285  3.482143  3.692308  4.483986  4.821429 [10]  6.000000  6.122449  6.176471  6.220736  6.260870  6.593407  7.010309  9.200000  9.473684 [19]  9.600000 12.600000 14.200000 16.146179 28.125000 30.099010 13.731343 14.432990 11.089109 [28] 17.960526 32.903226  8.955224 33.311688  8.800000 11.578947 20.000000 14.455446 18.181818 [37] 28.064516 25.684211 17.866667 23.142857 18.208955 20.536913 11.419355 11.593220 12.703583 [46] 20.000000  3.600000 11.320755  6.200000  6.575342 12.800000 19.109589 20.124224 22.941176 [55]  4.600000  6.600000  6.771160  8.000000 19.200000 19.400000 22.773723  3.333333  4.214047 [64]  5.106383 10.200000 12.240803  9.600000 15.789474  6.600000 13.333333 14.400000 30.000000 [73]  7.400000  8.400000  9.000000  9.709544 10.752688 15.800000  8.000000  9.729730 12.200000 [82] 16.909091 20.400000  4.000000  4.909091  5.217391  7.200000  9.800000  0.000000  4.166667

 show(logterrisize) [1] 1.3317643 1.3317643 1.3317643 0.1295798 0.1295798 1.5051368 1.5051368 1.5051368 1.5051368 [10] 1.5051368 1.5051368 1.5051368 1.5051368 1.5051368 1.5051368 1.5051368 1.5051368 1.5051368 [19] 1.5051368 1.5051368 1.5051368 1.4665993 1.4665993 1.4665993 1.8282328 1.8282328 1.9252934 [28] 1.9252934 1.9252934 2.3006582 2.3006582 2.5160920 2.7774040 2.7774040 3.3398623 3.3398623 [37] 3.4759297 1.2563594 1.6061204 1.6061204 1.7835139 1.7835139 2.1669498 2.1669498 2.1669498 [46] 2.1669498 0.7264997 0.7458155 0.8380524 0.8380524 0.8380524 0.8380524 0.8380524 0.8380524 [55] 1.1312118 1.7132464 1.7132464 1.7132464 1.7132464 1.7132464 1.7132464 2.0356960 2.0356960 [64] 2.0356960 2.0356960 2.0356960 2.1590311 2.1590311 0.5235444 0.5235444 0.5235444 0.5235444 [73] 0.6852007 0.6852007 0.6852007 0.6852007 0.6852007 0.6852007 1.2990139 1.2990139 1.2990139 [82] 1.2990139 1.2990139 1.5508422 1.5508422 1.5508422 1.5508422 1.5508422 1.1570730 1.1570730

show(teriid)[1]  2  2  2 79 79 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 63 24 24 24 27 27 21 21 21 23 23 26 [33] 22 22 20 20 19 38 40 40 39 39 35 35 35 35 53 56 55 55 55 55 55 55 57 54 54 54 54 54 54 58 58 58 [65] 58 58 60 60 86 86 86 86 50 50 50 50 50 50 48 48 48 48 48 47 47 47 47 47 51 51 51 51 51 51 51 51
```

StudyID contains the special ID of the study sites. All variables have the same number of rows.
Sorry if there is some information missing, but I will upload more data if requested.

Comment: Things to try: as your response seems to be continuous, use `lmer`, and `lmerControl`, and set the `maxfun` to a more reasonable number i.e. 1e4

Comment: okay; I constructed a small example. If `maxfun` has too large a number used it throws lots of errors even when using `lmer`. Models converge using a lower `maxfun`.

Comment: is that your whole data set? where are your `studyid` and `teriid` variables? what is `dput(Data_table_for_analysis_Character_studyarea)` ?

Comment: Valabe ; please can you add your data as `dput(Data_table_for_analysis_Character_studyarea)`, as BenBolker requested, or if you have lots of variables as `dput(Data_table_for_analysis_Character_studyarea[c("spm", "logterrisize", "studyarea", "teriid")])` . PS did you try using `lmer` and reducing `maxfun`?

Comment: @user20650 thanks a lot for your quick reply! I tried it with  1e4 for maxfun and it worked quite well. Furthermore, I used lmer() and lmerControl(), but then I got the warning message that "calling lmer with 'family' is deprecated; please use glmer() instead." I added my data as requested.

Comment: okay thanks. so the changing the `maxfun` has solved the problem? ... you dont need the `family` argument in `lmer` as it is for `gaussian` models

Comment: @user20650 yes it worked without any problems. Thanks! I have thought the family argument is always needed

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** yes, this looks like a bug/infelicity in `minqa::bobyqa`.

I was able to find a reproducible example and show that the warnings occur when `maxfun` is greater than the maximum value that can be represented in a long integer (32-bit signed, on most machines: `.Machine$integer.max` = 2147483647).  Unless something is terribly wrong, 2 **billion** optimization steps should be enough (among other things I'd be surprised if such an optimization would finish in a reasonable amount of time).

```
library(lme4)
gm1 <- glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period + (1 | herd),
             data = cbpp, family = binomial)
imax <- .Machine$integer.max ## 2147483647
tryfun <- function(n) {
    gm2 <- try(update(gm1, control=glmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",
                                                optCtrl=list(maxfun=n))),
               silent=TRUE)
    if (inherits(gm2,"try-error")) return(rep(NA,4))
    return(fixef(gm2))
}

tryfun(imax)
## (Intercept)     period2     period3     period4 
##  -1.3983316  -0.9919238  -1.1282144  -1.5797501 

tryfun(imax+1)
## (Intercept)     period2     period3     period4 
##  -1.4045886  -0.9349341  -1.0712274  -1.5124660
```

Without digging in further, I'm not sure what value of `maxfun` *actually* gets used when this problem occurs, but I suspect it's small. The second call produces:

> Warning messages:
>   1: In (function (par, fn, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf, control = list(),  :
>     NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
>   2: In optwrap(optimizer, devfun, start, rho$lower, control = control,  :
>     convergence code 1 from bobyqa: bobyqa -- maximum number of function evaluations exceeded
>   3: In (function (par, fn, lower = -Inf, upper = Inf, control = list(),  :
>     NAs introduced by coercion to integer range
>   4: In optwrap(optimizer, devfun, start, rho$lower, control = control,  :
>     convergence code 1 from bobyqa: bobyqa -- maximum number of function evaluations exceeded
>   5: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
>     Model failed to converge with max|grad| = 3.26758 (tol = 0.001, component 1)